# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Language could not be converted to string

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have form in my symfony2 application, but when I send form I get this message:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Language could not be       converted to string in  C:\wamp\www\Lingogo\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator.php line 205
```

I check my entities a lot of time, and all seems to by correct

Entity/Word.php

```
    <?php
//src/Lingogo/AdminBundle/Entity/Word.php

namespace Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Word
 * @package Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="words")
 */
class Word
{
    /**
     * @ORM\id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80)
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language", inversedBy="words")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $language;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updated;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Translation", mappedBy="word")
     */
    protected $translations;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Definition", mappedBy="word")
     */
    protected $definitions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->definitions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->translations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Word
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Word
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Word
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Add translations
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation $translations
     * @return Word
     */
    public function addTranslation(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation $translations)
    {
        $this->translations[] = $translations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove translations
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation $translations
     */
    public function removeTranslation(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation $translations)
    {
        $this->translations->removeElement($translations);
    }

    /**
     * Get translations
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTranslations()
    {
        return $this->translations;
    }

    /**
     * Add definitions
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Definition $definitions
     * @return Word
     */
    public function addDefinition(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Definition $definitions)
    {
        $this->definitions[] = $definitions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove definitions
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Definition $definitions
     */
    public function removeDefinition(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Definition $definitions)
    {
        $this->definitions->removeElement($definitions);
    }

    /**
     * Get definitions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDefinitions()
    {
        return $this->definitions;
    }

    /**
     * Set language
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Language $language
     * @return Word
     */
    public function setLanguage(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Language $language = null)
    {
        $this->language = $language;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get language
     *
     * @return \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Language 
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }
}
```

It's my second entity: Entity\Language.php

```
<?php
//src/Lingogo/AdminBundle/Entity/Language.php

namespace Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Language
 * @package Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="languages")
 */
class Language
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=90)
     */
    protected $language;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=6)
     */
    protected $locale;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Translation", mappedBy="languageTranslation")
     */
    protected $translations;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course", mappedBy="nativeLanguage")
     */
    protected $nativeLanguage;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course", mappedBy="courseLanguage")
     */
    protected $courseLanguage;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Definition", mappedBy="language")
     */
    protected $definitions;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Word", mappedBy="language")
     */
    protected $words;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translations = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->nativeLanguage = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->courseLanguage = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->definitions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->words = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set language
     *
     * @param string $language
     * @return Language
     */
    public function setLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->language = $language;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get language
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * Set locale
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @return Language
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locale
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    /**
     * Add translations
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation $translations
     * @return Language
     */
    public function addTranslation(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation $translations)
    {
        $this->translations[] = $translations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove translations
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation $translations
     */
    public function removeTranslation(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation $translations)
    {
        $this->translations->removeElement($translations);
    }

    /**
     * Get translations
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTranslations()
    {
        return $this->translations;
    }

    /**
     * Add nativeLanguage
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course $nativeLanguage
     * @return Language
     */
    public function addNativeLanguage(\Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course $nativeLanguage)
    {
        $this->nativeLanguage[] = $nativeLanguage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove nativeLanguage
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course $nativeLanguage
     */
    public function removeNativeLanguage(\Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course $nativeLanguage)
    {
        $this->nativeLanguage->removeElement($nativeLanguage);
    }

    /**
     * Get nativeLanguage
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getNativeLanguage()
    {
        return $this->nativeLanguage;
    }

    /**
     * Add courseLanguage
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course $courseLanguage
     * @return Language
     */
    public function addCourseLanguage(\Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course $courseLanguage)
    {
        $this->courseLanguage[] = $courseLanguage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove courseLanguage
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course $courseLanguage
     */
    public function removeCourseLanguage(\Lingogo\PortalBundle\Entity\Course $courseLanguage)
    {
        $this->courseLanguage->removeElement($courseLanguage);
    }

    /**
     * Get courseLanguage
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCourseLanguage()
    {
        return $this->courseLanguage;
    }

    /**
     * Add definitions
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Definition $definitions
     * @return Language
     */
    public function addDefinition(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Definition $definitions)
    {
        $this->definitions[] = $definitions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove definitions
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Definition $definitions
     */
    public function removeDefinition(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Definition $definitions)
    {
        $this->definitions->removeElement($definitions);
    }

    /**
     * Get definitions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getDefinitions()
    {
        return $this->definitions;
    }

    /**
     * Add words
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Word $words
     * @return Language
     */
    public function addWord(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Word $words)
    {
        $this->words[] = $words;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove words
     *
     * @param \Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Word $words
     */
    public function removeWord(\Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Word $words)
    {
        $this->words->removeElement($words);
    }

    /**
     * Get words
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getWords()
    {
        return $this->words;
    }
}
```

and my Form\Type\WordType.php

```
<?php
//src/Lingogo/AdminBundle/Form/WordType.php

namespace Lingogo\AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class WordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        $builder->add('language', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'LingogoAdminBundle:Language',
            'property' => 'language',
            'empty_value' =>'Please select language'
        ));
        $builder->add('add', 'submit');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'=> 'Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Word'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'word';
    }
}
```

What I do wrong? What I shoud do to save my form ?

I found problem, I had the validation

```
Lingogo\AdminBundle\Entity\Word:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: { message: "word.name.not_blank" }
        language:
            - Choice: { choices: [pl, en], message: "word.language.choice"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `__toString()` method to your `Language` entity class - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: When I added __toString() I received this error: word.language.choice
So I checked my validation, and I found this constraint on language:
- Choice: { choices: [pl, en], message: "word.language.choice"}

I deleted this validation, and this resolved my problem.